# search text box utility

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a requirement where user will have an option to search
the data and should match the feature same as google has provided

i.e. whatever char user types in the search box - user will be prompted with matching string below - same as google search text box - you type something and get the options
what control or strategy we should follow in C# ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is called auto-complete or auto-suggest feature. search with these keywords and you will get plenty of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "autocomplete". The Ajax Control Toolkit has such a control. You can find it [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to achieve is basically AJAX based Google like "suggest" feature, I would recommend having a look at this : [Google like search](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-.html)

Plus there are ample other such links that will help you in your quest.